# [Mongoose error]: conn.openUri(...).then is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hy guys, i am developing my application using mongodb and nodejs, but returns this error: **conn.openUri(...).then is not a function**

my connection:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

mongoose.connect('url', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
})
```

mongoose version: **v5.10.0**

who can help please

Comment: where do you see `openUri` in mongoose docs?

Comment: if is that, **node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js\339:47**


    `Mongoose.prototype.connect = function(uri, options, callback) {

      const _mongoose = this instanceof Mongoose ? this : mongoose;

      const conn = _mongoose.connection;

      return conn.openUri(uri, options, callback).then(() => _mongoose);
    };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with mongoose at **v5.10.0**

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9335

There are a few possible solutions.

1. **Recommended** - install mongoose at the previous version. **v5.9.29**. If using npm you can `npm uninstall mongoose` `npm install mongoose@5.9.29 --save-exact`.
2. You can connect using `createConnection` instead.

### EDIT

By this time the issue has been fixed in version 5.10.1 of mongoose.
so the best you can do is to upgrade mongoose to the latest version.